# IE10 - div:hover Only Partially Working, Breaking Down Between Inner-div Links

Tags: html, css, hover, internet-explorer-10

While trying to find a fix for this problem I've discovered I am not alone in having IE :hover issues, but I have not found a single working solution.

Menu works in current versions of Chrome and Firefox perfectly, but breaks down in IE10 (haven't tested others).

I have a ~1/4 circle drop down menu at the top center of the page that expands to about 3/4 of the circle when hovered over. It has four sections (links) which each expand separately when hovered over to show child links.

The problem is that the :hover effect appears to only work when hovering over the actual links although the :hover is applied to the containing divs. This wouldn't be SO bad, except that when a section expands each space between link text causes the section to close. It makes the menu very choppy and hard to use.

EDIT: Link to Fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/2GzsQ/2/

Here is the HTML for the menu:

```
<div id="navholder" class="">
            <div id="navservice" class="outernav">
                <a href="" alt="Services"><h2>Services</h2></a>
                <div id="innavservice" class="innernav">
                    <a href="">Specimens</a> | <a href="">Collection Access</a> | <a href="">Identification</a> | <a href="">Books</a><br>
                    <a href="">Destructive Sampling</a> | <a href="">Loans</a> | <a href="">Specimen Submission</a><br>
                    <a href="">Specimen Labels</a> | <a href="">Quarantine</a> | <a href="">Data Use Conditions</a><br>
                    <a href="">Specimen Images</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="navprojects" class="outernav">
                <a href="" alt="Projects"><h2>Projects</h2></a>
                <div id="innavprojects" class="innernav">
                    <a href="">Legumes of Arizona</a> | <a href="">Biodiversity Informatics</a> | <a href="">Floras</a><br>
                    <a href="">Nichol Turk's Head Cactus Working Group</a> | <a href="">Section 6</a><br>
                    <a href="">National Park Service</a> | <a href="">Pringle's Arizona Catalog</a><br>
                    <a href="">Type Imaging</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="navresources" class="outernav">
                <a href="" alt="Resources"><h2>Resources</h2></a>
                <div id="innavresources" class="innernav">
                    <a href="">Convolvulaceae Pollen Atlas</a> | <a href="">Shantz Photographs</a><br>
                    <a href="">Convolvulaceae of Sonora</a> | <a href="">Floras for Other Regions</a><br>
                    <a href="">Arizona Floras and Floristic Works</a> | <a href="">Publications</a><br>
                    <a href="">Homer Shantz</a> | <a href="">Sample Photos</a> | <a href="">Links</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="navariz" class="outernav">
                <a href="" alt="About"><h2>About</h2></a>
                <div id="innavariz" class="innernav">
                    <a href="">What is an Herbarium</a> | <a href="">About ARIZ</a><br>
                    <a href="">People</a> | <a href="">Associated Researchers</a><br>
                    <a href="">Our Logo</a> | <a href="">History</a> | <a href="">Donations</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And, here is the CSS for the menu:

```
/* div containing drop-down top white circle navigation */
#navigationc {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    top: -150px;
    z-index: 3;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s;
    transition: top 0.5s;
}

/* drop-down functionality */
#navigationc:hover {
    top: 0;
}

/* Circle navigation */

/* moves #navservice div to top of drop-down navigation */
#navholder:hover #navservice {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

/* contains the collection of links within each navigation section */
.innernav {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
    transition: height 0.5s;
}

/* the first main section of the drop-down navigation menu */
#navservice {
    margin-top: 155px;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top 1s;
    -moz-transition: margin-top 1s;
    transition: margin-top 1s;
}

/* expands each menu section when it is hovered over to expose child links */
#navservice:hover #innavservice {
    height: 105px;
}

#navprojects:hover #innavprojects {
    height: 105px;
}

#navresources:hover #innavresources {
    height: 105px;
}

#navariz:hover #innavariz {
    height: 105px;
}
```

Maybe this is just a problem that I will have to accept, but I feel there must be a solution. Thank you.

## NOTE - All of the empty href's above are real links, but links were removed to post on SE.

Comment: Show a live example. (Don’t expect others to go through a copy&paste orgy to help _you_ with _your_ problem.)

Comment: Okay, I made a fiddle which is at least demonstrating the functionality. http://jsfiddle.net/2GzsQ/

Comment: _“I have a ~1/4 circle drop down menu at the top center of the page”_ – I don’t see anything that resembles a circle even closely …

Comment: I was unable to get the fiddle to reproduce the problem, BUT adding the SVG circle to the equation introduces the problem. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2GzsQ/2/

Comment: Would adding a *nearly* transparent background to the default state help IE10+ notice the element is being hovered when it is? `#navigationc { background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.01) }` as in http://jsfiddle.net/2GzsQ/4/ Sorry I can't even test my fiddle on a device with IE10+ with a mouse for now  but it's very close to a problem I encountered in the past...

Comment: I have seen some people online saying that a lack of background has been the problem, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I ended up using a PNG for a background instead of an SVG, but that didn't make a difference either. I'll try setting the background of #navigationc to a blank image next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was setting the SVG (a 460px semi-transparent white circle) as the background image for the div containing it.

When originally making the theme I avoided doing that in the first place for some reason, but it appears to no longer be a problem.

The original problem: using the :hover pseudo-class on a div (and divs within this one) that is positioned over and above (z-index) an image (tried SVG and PNG in this case) was not fully functional in IE10. The effects defined within the :hover classes failed when hovering on any space between or outside of the anchor elements within the divs (which :hover was applied to).

Maybe someone with a better understanding can explain why this happens, and hopefully this will help someone out.